# Group by with case statement fails group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
PROCEDURE
---------
id  INT
SERVICE_TYPE  VARCHAR(20)
TIMEUNITS (INT)
UNITS (INT)
```

I am trying to run this sql code:

```
select SERVICE_TYPE, 
       case when TIMEUNITS > 1 THEN SUM(1) 
       WHEN UNITS > 1 THEN SUM(UNITS) 
       END
group by SERVICE_TYPE
```

My problem is that I"m told that TIMEUNITS is not grouped nor aggregated by...

how do I repair this query?
thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please paste the exact query that caused the problem. The one you have now has syntax errors.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight . . . That is actually the point of the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I doubt that this query could produce the "not grouped not aggregated" error, because `END` is missing on the `CASE`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I had a similar thought but it probably wasn't copied correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I had to sanitize my query.  Had special data in it.  I wrote it parallel to my original query from my head.  I'll update the END.  but Gordon got me exactly where I needed to go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For conditional aggregation, the `case` expression is the argument to the aggregation function.  For example, to get the number of rows where `timeunits > 1`:

```
select SERVICE_TYPE,
       sum(case when timeunits > 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by SERVICE_TYPE;
```